# How to pass query string of old domain to new domain using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Eg:

```
http://www.old-domain.com/news.php?NewsID=30888&test=3
```

to:

```
http://www.new-domain.com/?NewsID=30888&test=3
```

I need to get only the parameters on new domain not page 'news.php'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens by default when you use a redirect or a rewrite. For example, in the htaccess file in the document root of the `old-domain.com` domain:

```
Redirect 301 /news.php http://www.new-domain.com/
```

Any query string (e.g. `?NewsID=30888&test=3`) that went to `/news.php` will automatically get appended to `http://www.new-domain.com/`.

Same with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^news.php$ http://www.new-domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

---

EDIT: valuable information:

> n my case, it may occur any pages apart from the news.php, so it is not based on news.php. I simply need the parameters on new domain that may from any pages. Eg: `old-domain.com/pagename.php?var1=data1&var2=data2` to `new-domain.com/?var1=data1&var2=data2`

Then that would be:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*) http://www.new-domain.com/
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new-domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Like I said in my answer, the actual paths are irrelevant. **The query string gets appended automatically, you don't need to do anything special**.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but i am not expecting this. In my case, it may occur any pages apart from the news.php, so it is not based on news.php. I simply need the parameters on new domain that may from any pages.

Eg: http://www.old-domain.com/pagename.php?var1=data1&var2=data2
 to
 http://www.new-domain.com/?var1=data1&var2=data2